# Colour Code an edge in JUNG

Tags: java, jung

I am trying to generate a dynamic graph using JUNG, based on the data I receive. I want the edges to be colour coded automatically and not based on any condition. I was trying to work out with this code, but this fails as well:

```
Transformer<String, Paint> edgePaint = new Transformer<String, Paint>() 
    {
        private final Color[] palette = {Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW, Color.RED, Color.GRAY, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, Color.WHITE, Color.orange};
        int i=0;
        @Override
        public Paint transform(String graphEdge) 
        {
            if(i == 7)
            {
                i = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                i = i + 1;
            }
            return palette[i];

        }
    };
    viewer.getRenderContext().setEdgeDrawPaintTransformer(edgePaint);
```

My edges are Strings and are not predictable to have a condition set up. I need one colour for each edge and also, it shouldn't change when I zoom in and zoom out. Is this possible ?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "colour coded automatically".  What criteria do you want to use for determining the color of an edge?

Comment: For each edge being added, I want a color. No criteria.

1st Edge added -  color 1
2nd Edge added  - color 2
3rd Edge added - color 3

Answer (score 0):

(1) If you really want to just assign colors in order, wrapping around a list (e.g., R-G-B-R-G-B-R-G...), then you can define a Map, and populate it however you like (e.g., iterate through your edges and assign each a color).  Then have the Transformer just return

```
edgeColor.get(graphEdge)
```

(2) If you don't really care in what order the colors will be used, or if you get the occasional repeat, then you can get the hashCode of the edge, mod it to the length of the color list, and return that:

```
palette[graphEdge.hashCode() % palette.length];
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but will these colours change if I zoom in or zoom out the graph ?

Comment: No, they won't.  The reason they're changing in your current implementation is that you're picking a new color for each edge every time the transformer is called, which is every time the graph is repainted.  Either of the solutions I proposed would give you a consistent color for each edge.  (Incidentally, based on the kind of questions you're asking, I recommend that you check out some Java tutorials.)

Comment: I figured it out only now that the Graph was being repainted everytime it was zoomed it or zoomed out. I'm used to jfreeChart where we can set a color, but then it doesn't allow graph views. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample answer when have an approximatation on the number of edges:

Also this avoids assigning the same colour to more than one edge.

```
  Transformer<String, Paint> edgePaint = new Transformer<String, Paint>() 
    {
        private final Color[] palette = {Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW, Color.RED, Color.GRAY, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, Color.WHITE, Color.ORANGE};
        int[] boolFlag = new int[palette.length];

        @Override
        public Paint transform(String graphEdge) 
        {
            int colorNumber = Math.abs(graphEdge.hashCode() % palette.length);
            if(boolFlag[colorNumber] != 1)
            {
                boolFlag[colorNumber] = 1;
                return palette[colorNumber];
            }

            else
            {
                int i=0;
                for(i=0; i < palette.length; i++)
                    if(boolFlag[i] != 1)
                    {
                        colorNumber = i;
                        break;
                    }
                if( i == palette.length)
                {
                    for(i=0; i< palette.length; i++)
                        boolFlag[i] =0;
                }
                boolFlag[colorNumber] = 1;
                return palette[colorNumber];
            }
        }
    };
```